# How can I extract the data from these strings?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am making a program that consists of scraping data from a job page, and I get to this data

```
{"job":{"ciphertext":"~01142b81f148312a7c","rid":225177647,"uid":"1416152499115024384","type":2,"access":4,"title":"Need app developers to handle our app upgrades","status":1,"category":{"name":"Mobile Development","urlSlug":"mobile-development"
,"contractorTier":2,"description":"We have an app currently built, we are looking for someone to \n\n1) Manage the app for bugs etc \n2) Provide feature upgrades \n3) Overall Management and optimization \n\nPlease get in touch and i will share more details. ","questions":null,"qualifications":{"type":0,"location":null,"minOdeskHours":0,"groupRecno":0,"shouldHavePortfolio":false,"tests":null,"minHoursWeek":40,"group":null,"prefEnglishSkill":0,"minJobSuccessScore":0,"risingTalent":true,"locationCheckRequired":false,"countries":null,"regions":null,"states":null,"timezones":null,"localMarket":false,"onSiteType":null,"locations":null,"localDescription":null,"localFlexibilityDescription":null,"earnings":null,"languages":null
],"clientActivity":{"lastBuyerActivity":null,"totalApplicants":0,"totalHired":0,"totalInvitedToInterview":0,"unansweredInvites":0,"invitationsSent":0
,"buyer":{"isPaymentMethodVerified":false,"location":{"offsetFromUtcMillis":14400000,"countryTimezone":"United Arab Emirates (UTC+04:00)","city":"Dubai","country":"United Arab Emirates"
,"stats":{"totalAssignments":31,"activeAssignmentsCount":3,"feedbackCount":27,"score":4.9258937139,"totalJobsWithHires":30,"hoursCount":7.16666667,"totalCharges":{"currencyCode":"USD","amount":19695.83
,"jobs":{"postedCount":59,"openCount":2
,"avgHourlyJobsRate":{"amount":19.999534874418824
```

But the problem is that the only data I need is:
-Title
-Description
-Customer activity (lastBuyerActivity, totalApplicants, totalHired, totalInvitedToInterview, unansweredInvites, invitationsSent)
-Buyer (isPaymentMethodVerified, location (Country))
-stats (All items)
-jobs (all items)
-avgHourlyJobsRate

Comment: I mean this is a simple dictionary lookup. To get the title you say dict_name["job"]["Title"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sort of data are JSON type data. Python understands these sort of data through *dictionary* data type.
Suppose you have your data stored in a string. You can use `di = exec(myData)` to convert the string to dictionary. Then you can access the structured data like: `di["job"]` which return's the *job* section of the data.

```py
di = exec(myData)
print(`di["job"]`)
```

However this is just a hack and it is not recommended because it's a
bit messy and *unpythonic*.
The appropriate way is to use JSON library to convert the data to dictionary. Take a look at the code snippet below to get an idea of what is the appropriate way:

```py
import json

myData = "Put your data Here"
res = json.loads(myData)
print(res["jobs"])
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the data to dictionary using json.loads

then you can easily use the dictionary keys that your want to lookup or filter the data.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a dictionary so you can extract something from it by doing: `dictionary["job"]["uid"]` for example. If it is a Json file convert the data to a Python dictionary